# Question re: Dropbox Security Breach and how this happens in production environment

Tags: security, dropbox

For reference: http://news.cnet.com/8301-31921_3-20072755-281/dropbox-confirms-security-glitch-no-password-required/.  Can someone explain to me how this bug can happen if they properly tested this on a staging server with an identical environment to production?  I'm trying to understand if it was just a random mistake that could happen to anyone, or if it was just negligence on their part.  Thx in advance for any input!

Comment: More on-topic over at security.stackexchange.com than here. Suggest migration.

Comment: @Rory Alsop, sorry, I'm always on stack overflow, so it was just by habit.  Hopefully a mod can move it for me.
@downvoter, why the downvote?  It's just a question, sheesh.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me - I think it is a good question, just for another SE site :-)

Comment: @Rory Alsop, I didn't think it was you :), was thinking more that it would be the dropbox pr/social media dept or some fanboy.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it could happen to anyone in testing - after all, after you've tested a very secure Dropbox system for a few years you don't expect to need to test blank passwords - but I think that is negligence on the development team's part. When you think about it, there is just no way a flaw like that could be unintentional (maybe the developers wanted to try it out and not have to keep entering passwords - I don't know) because they should employ hashing and all, and even if they didn't even protect against injection in any way a blank password could never match.

I'm not on the Dropbox development team, so I don't know what exactly happened. All you can do is guess. I'm probably completely wrong about this and maybe it was some sort of small technical problem that could easily be overlooked. I don't know.

Comment: thx for replying.  Shouldn't they at the very least have a testing suite that would check for bugs?  I'm not really understanding how a company like Dropbox could allow something like this to happen.

Comment: @blacktie24: They probably should - I don't actually know if they do. It's just such an obvious bug, maybe they overlooked it.

Comment: maybe someone messed around with the code without really knowing what he's doing. senior manager: "well, I need to insert this picture, I think my 10 year old son knows some html, I shouldn't bother programmers"

Answer (score 2):

It often comes down to how extensive the test phase can be - far too often the budget goes on making sure the product looks good to customers, or is out the door by a specific deadline.

It is exceedingly rare to find a company that builds security testing in from the start and has it as required for go-live. Security spend is almost always the first to be cut when a project is over budget or time.

So my guess is that there was a time budget during there was enough to fit in the main functional tests and the 'highest risk' security tests and then it was released.

Comment: surely an empty password would class under 'highest risk' can't think of anything that is much worse

Comment: But if the change didn't appear to touch passwords (ie code was changed for something else and this was an accident) then this risk may not appear on their list

Comment: if they had a standard testing suite in place, surely it would be quite easy to catch this bug.  It just puzzles me as to how a company as big as Dropbox, and as important as security is to them, wouldn't have ANY regression testing in place.

Comment: @blacktie - that is the problem. Many companies would like to have standard testing suites, that the devs want to use, but that are partially discarded when deadlines loom, or budget is removed. I agree it is wrong, and I'll be delighted when companies treat security testing with the same respect as functional testing.